# Get "value" and use it in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a little problem in JavaScript.
I'm doing a gallery page. There is a icon with "Onclik" that calls function "comment".

```
function comment() {

var div = document.getElementById("commentdiv");
var input = document.createElement("textarea");
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t = document.createTextNode("ADD");  

input.name = "post";
input.maxLength = "5000";

btn.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(btn);  

div.appendChild(input); 
div.appendChild(btn);
btn.style.width='100%';
btn.style.height='30px';

input.style.width='100%';
input.style.height='150px';

msn = input.value;
btn.onclick=write;

}
```

But there is problem. When I do input.value, there isn't nothing in input. I want in msn, the text that people write in the textarea. 
When I calling the second function, doesn't write because is empty.

```
function write() {


 document.getElementById("commentdiv").innerHTML += + msn ;

}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Because `msn` value was taken when element was just created, you need to take fresh values from the `textarea`

```
function write() 
{
   document.getElementById("callate").innerHTML += document.querySelector( "#commentdiv textarea" ).value ;
}
```

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `msn` as global variable. Also remove `+` left of the `msn`

```
var msn;
function comment() {
   msn = input.value;
}

function write() {
   document.getElementById("commentdiv").innerHTML += msn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `write` function to be :

```
function write() {
   document.getElementById("commentdiv").innerHTML += input.value ;
}
```